# Beaver ponds on stream profiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, profile, hydrology-toolset

I have a shapefile with polygons of beaver ponds and a DEM of the area of river watershed where ponds are located.

I want to check if a river gradient and a river valley shape effect area of a pond.

I've created graphs of a river vertical profile and river cross sections in pond locations using 3D analyst of ArcGIS but I want to see my ponds on those graphs.

Is there a way to insert the pond data into the created graphs or some other way to show on one graph a pond and river profile?